# Uppercase vs. capitalized environment variable names during debug

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, environment-variables

What could cause the following different behavior during a debug vs. launch session?

In eclipse-debug and maven-run I get all environment variables in uppercase while in eclipse-run some remain as defined in windows.

```
@Test
public void testEnvironmentVariables() {
    ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(System.getenv().keySet());
    Collections.sort(keys);
    System.out.println(keys);
}
```

The output if executed by **Run**: notice `http.proxyUser`

`[=::, ALLUSERSPROFILE, APPDATA, APR_ICONV_PATH, CLASSPATH, CLINK_DIR, COMPUTERNAME, ChocolateyBinRoot, ChocolateyInstall, ComSpec, CommonProgramFiles, CommonProgramFiles(x86), CommonProgramW6432, DEBUG_PORT, DEFLOGDIR, EC_COMPUTER_OU, EC_HOMEAPPDATA, EC_USER_DEPARTMENT, EC_USER_DG, EC_USER_DISPLAY_NAME, EC_USER_ELK, EC_USER_OU, EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES, FP_NO_HOST_CHECK, GRADLE_HOME, HOMEDRIVE, HOMEPATH, JAVA_HOME, JAVA_OPTS, LDMS_LOCAL_DIR, LOCALAPPDATA, LOGONSERVER, LocalRunSetup, M2, M2_HOME, M2_REPO, MAVEN_OPTS, MW_HOME, NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS, ORACLE_BASE, ORACLE_HOME, OS, PATH2, PATHEXT, PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE, PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER, PROCESSOR_LEVEL, PROCESSOR_REVISION, PSModulePath, PUBLIC, Path, ProgramData, ProgramFiles, ProgramFiles(x86), ProgramW6432, SBT_HOME, SESSIONNAME, SFT_SOFTGRIDSERVER, SystemDrive, SystemRoot, TEMP, TMP, USERDNSDOMAIN, USERDOMAIN, USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE, USERNAME, USERPROFILE, UUMDS_CFG, VAGRANT_HOME, VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH, VSEDEFLOGDIR, chocolatey_bin_root, debugFlag, http.proxyHost, http.proxyPassword, http.proxyPort, http.proxyUser, http_proxy, https.proxyHost, https.proxyPassword, https.proxyPort, https.proxyUser, https_proxy, myProxy, no_proxy, uumds.config.location, windir, windows_tracing_flags, windows_tracing_logfile]`

The output if executed by **Debug**: notice `HTTP.PROXYUSER`

`[ALLUSERSPROFILE, APPDATA, APR_ICONV_PATH, CHOCOLATEYBINROOT, CHOCOLATEYINSTALL, CHOCOLATEY_BIN_ROOT, CLASSPATH, CLINK_DIR, COMMONPROGRAMFILES, COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86), COMMONPROGRAMW6432, COMPUTERNAME, COMSPEC, DEBUGFLAG, DEBUG_PORT, DEFLOGDIR, EC_COMPUTER_OU, EC_HOMEAPPDATA, EC_USER_DEPARTMENT, EC_USER_DG, EC_USER_DISPLAY_NAME, EC_USER_ELK, EC_USER_OU, EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES, FP_NO_HOST_CHECK, GRADLE_HOME, HOMEDRIVE, HOMEPATH, HTTP.PROXYHOST, HTTP.PROXYPASSWORD, HTTP.PROXYPORT, HTTP.PROXYUSER, HTTPS.PROXYHOST, HTTPS.PROXYPASSWORD, HTTPS.PROXYPORT, HTTPS.PROXYUSER, HTTPS_PROXY, HTTP_PROXY, JAVA_HOME, JAVA_OPTS, LDMS_LOCAL_DIR, LOCALAPPDATA, LOCALRUNSETUP, LOGONSERVER, M2, M2_HOME, M2_REPO, MAVEN_OPTS, MW_HOME, MYPROXY, NO_PROXY, NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS, ORACLE_BASE, ORACLE_HOME, OS, PATH, PATH2, PATHEXT, PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE, PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER, PROCESSOR_LEVEL, PROCESSOR_REVISION, PROGRAMDATA, PROGRAMFILES, PROGRAMFILES(X86), PROGRAMW6432, PROMPT, PSMODULEPATH, PUBLIC, SBT_HOME, SESSIONNAME, SFT_SOFTGRIDSERVER, SYSTEMDRIVE, SYSTEMROOT, TEMP, TMP, USERDNSDOMAIN, USERDOMAIN, USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE, USERNAME, USERPROFILE, UUMDS.CONFIG.LOCATION, UUMDS_CFG, VAGRANT_HOME, VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH, VSEDEFLOGDIR, WINDIR, WINDOWS_TRACING_FLAGS, WINDOWS_TRACING_LOGFILE]`

If executed from **maven**: notice `HTTP.PROXYUSER`

`testEnvironment=[=::, =C:, =EXITCODE, ALLUSERSPROFILE, APPDATA, APR_ICONV_PATH, CHOCOLATEYBINROOT, CHOCOLATEYINSTALL, CHOCOLATEY_BIN_ROOT, CLASSPATH, CLASSWORLDS_JAR, CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER, CLINK_DIR, COMMANDER_DRIVE, COMMANDER_EXE, COMMANDER_INI, COMMANDER_PATH, COMMONPROGRAMFILES, COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86), COMMONPROGRAMW6432, COMPUTERNAME, COMSPEC, DEBUGFLAG, DEBUG_PORT, DEFLOGDIR, EC_COMPUTER_OU, EC_HOMEAPPDATA, EC_USER_DEPARTMENT, EC_USER_DG, EC_USER_DISPLAY_NAME, EC_USER_ELK, EC_USER_OU, ERROR_CODE, EXEC_DIR, EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES,
 FP_NO_HOST_CHECK, GRADLE_HOME, HOME, HOMEDRIVE, HOMEPATH, HTTP.PROXYHOST, HTTP.PROXYPASSWORD, HTTP.PROXYPORT, HTTP.PROXYUSER, HTTPS.PROXYHOST, HTTPS.PROXYPASSWORD, HTTPS.PROXYPORT, HTTPS.PROXYUSER, HTTPS_PROXY, HTTP_PROXY, JAVA_HOME, JAVA_OPTS, LDMS_LOCAL_DIR, LOCALAPPDATA, LOCALRUNSETUP, LOGONSERVER, M2, M2_HOME, M2_REPO, MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS, MAVEN_JAVA_EXE, MAVEN_OPTS, MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR, MW_HOME, MYPROXY, NO_PROXY, NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS, ORACLE_BASE, ORACLE_HOME, OS, PATH, PATH2, PATHEXT, PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE, PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER, PROCESSOR_LEVEL, PROCESSOR_REVISION, PROGRAMDATA, PROGRAMFILES, PROGRAMFILES(X86), PROGRAMW6432, PROMPT, PSMODULEPATH, PUBLIC, SBT_HOME, SESSIONNAME, SFT_SOFTGRIDSERVER, SYSTEMDRIVE, SYSTEMROOT, TEMP, TMP, USERDNSDOMAIN, USERDOMAIN, USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE, USERNAME, USERPROFILE, UUMDS.CONFIG.LOCATION, UUMDS_CFG, VAGRANT_HOME, VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH, VSEDEFLOGDIR, WDIR, WINDIR, WINDOWS_TRACING_FLAGS, WINDOWS_TRACING_LOGFILE]`

I found a similar question here: *[Uppercase vs. capitalized environment variable names during debug [message #242568]](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=77986&goto=242568&#msg_242568)*, but without any answer.

I'm using Java 8 on Windows 7 and Eclipse v4.6 (Neon).

```
>java -version
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers
Version: Neon Release (4.6.0)
Build id: 20160613-1800

> mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T13:57:37+02:00)
Maven home: C:\costin\apps\apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_77, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Comment: Noone garatuees to have the same order. Whats not specified that can be random (at least in the future). Do you use the same VM-Version?

Comment: @PeterRader, I think he refers to the case of the variables, not the order itself. Good question, by the way.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Ah the case? Its a bad question then because the hashmaps filled by http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/ProcessEnvironment.java#71 are different.

Comment: I was expecting to see different ordering, that's why I sorted them. The problem is that I get different environment variables depending on how I execute the test/main class: by selecting from the eclipse menu: Run>Run As>JUnit Test or Run>Debug As>Junit Test.

Comment: Even stranger, it’s not just case that differs:  ChocolateyBinRoot, CHOCOLATEY_BIN_ROOT, CHOCOLATEYBINROOT.

Answer (score 1):

You are not debugging using [JPDA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/). Using JPDA you see exactly the same HashMap used in [System](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/ProcessEnvironment.java#71). You must be using two different VM executions because the order of the keys differs, this is not a 100% Java debugging.

In two different processes you can have different namings for the execution by using system-properties before environment-variables.

Comment: You are drawing strange conclusions from the claimed difference in the key order. First, as far as the same keys are present, the order does *not* differ. Second, the reason, the order does not differ, is that there is an explicit `Collections.sort(keys)` before the print statement.

Comment: You're right I'm not debugging using JPDA. I'm doing this in eclipse. I execute the test class: by selecting from the eclipse menu: Run>Run As>JUnit Test or Run>Debug As>Junit Test.

Comment: @Holger I realy think `uumds.config.location` is at the wrong position!